# Java - use password in a properties file

Tags: java, properties

I work on a source code I have to readapt in order to publish a second version of a software.

More precisely, I have to change a FTP connection settings. All is ok.
I'd like to improve the code by using a password located on a properties file (and not inside a *.java class).
The problem is when I make my modifications (and after when I compile the source code), the FTP connection button of the tool looks like inactive and the connection is impossible.
Why ?  Is that the use of the `FileInputStream` component ?

To be more practical, here is the snippet I'm working on :

```
void checkConnection(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    final String adress = uiURL.getText();
    if (adress == null || adress.isEmpty()) {
        Rhomeo.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Impossible");
    }
    // Adapt
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream input = null;
    input = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/Pass2.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    final String pw2 = prop.getProperty("password");
    // End Adapt

    final int port = uiPort.getValue();
    final String workDir = uiDir.getText();
    final String login = uiLogin.getText();

    final TaskManager.MockTask t = new TaskManager.MockTask(() -> FTPAccess.createClient(adress, port, workDir, login, pw2));

    t.setOnSucceeded(
        (evt) -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (t.getValue() != null) {
                Rhomeo.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Connexion établie");
            } else {
                Rhomeo.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Aucune réponse du serveur !");
            }
        })
    );


    t.setOnFailed(evt -> Platform.runLater(() -> GeotkFX.newExceptionDialog("Impossible de se connecter au service FTP", t.getException()).show()));

    t.runningProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> uiTest.setDisable(newValue));
    TaskManager.INSTANCE.submit("Test de connexion", t);
}
```

I'm really getting stick. So any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: What is pw2 set to when stepping through the code? Is it also worth showing your properties file?

Comment: pw2 get the password located in the properties file.

Comment: @Julian We really need more in order to help you. We need to see the contents of your properties file for a start. I suspect the issue is appearing after the program is compiled.
Try hard coding a location for the FileInputStream eg "C:\Pass2.properties" (assuming windows) then compile and see if it works. (Make sure the file exists in that location obviously.)

Comment: The content of the properties file is this one : **password=fd1254x?a**.  Before posting my question I tried what you explain with a System.out.println and no problems : I got the content of the properties file.

Comment: @Julian. It sounds like there isnt an issue with the application reading from a properties file then. The issue with your connection button being greyed out is stemming from somewhere else.

Comment: If you think it is an issue with the file being open you could use input.close() after reading the property. It would be good practice to anyway. But i dont think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you load your .properties file using a classLoader:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Pass2.properties");
prop.load(input);
```

This will load your resource from the classpath, so make sure it contains your .properties file

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you suggest but same problem.. The connection button doesn't work and seems to be desactivated..